# Read unknown parameters json javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read a json from javascript. I already am able to read the file but I have some problems retrieving info from that file because of its structure. I don't know the name of some levels...

This is an example:

```
{
    "zona": [{
        "zona1": [{
            "lon": "-3.841867446899414",
            "lat": "43.466002139041116"
        }, {
            "lon": "-3.838176727294922",
            "lat": "43.466002139041116"
        }, {
            "lon": "-3.838348388671875",
            "lat": "43.46432016607394"
        }, {
            "lon": "-3.843669891357422",
            "lat": "43.46276274196949"
        }]
    }, {
        "zona2": [{
            "lon": "-3.832254409790039",
            "lat": "43.462513550389424"
        }, {
            "lon": "-3.8265037536621094",
            "lat": "43.46375949801845"
        }, {
            "lon": "-3.8254737854003906",
            "lat": "43.461641371770504"
        }, {
            "lon": "-3.829936981201172",
            "lat": "43.46002157809642"
        }, {
            "lon": "-3.832683563232422",
            "lat": "43.461142978339005"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I tried to do something like this but I think I was a little bit innocent lol

```
function fun() {
    var zona;
    $.getJSON('listaPuntosZona.json', function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.zona.length; i++) {
            zonaX = 'zona' + (i + 1);
            alert(data.zona[i].zonaX.length);
        }
    });
```

I have read about foreach loops but I don't understand them so I can't write a code for them. Is there a way to do as I am thinking?
Third parameter, ZonaX goes from zona1 to zonaN but 1,2,3....N, always +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explore unknown JSON/object structures you may call the function walk(data) as
... function(data) {walk(data); ...

```
        function walk(data) {
            if(typeof(data) == "object") {
                for(key in data) {
                   console.log(key+": "+data[key]);
                   walk(data[key]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I have to make some changes to adapt to my webpage but I think I can use your function almost complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (key in data.zone)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use jQuery, so we iterate through the array the jQuery way:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    $.each(this, function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        $.each(this, function(index) {
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
});
```

Take a look at your JavaScript console and you'll understand how it works and read the jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/